# Login Model for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication, design-patterns

can you help me with my problem:

i have ASP.NET web site that have some basic authorization features (Login/Logoout e.t.c.). Currently i have 3 main methods:

- bool Login(string name, string password);
- bool IsLogged();
- string GetUserID();

All this methods are "hardcoded" into one class. Login methods checks database to determine that user exists. But then I've decided to use XML file to store users, it means that all logic that checked a user should be rewritten.

I've got an idea to use the following "pattern":

1. Create interface (e.g. ILoginProvider) that declares those 3 methods that described above
2. Implement this interface in any class and write specific logic in Login() method to check XML file or database
3. Pass this class to ??? (here is my problem)

I thought to make a class (e.g. LoginHelper) that can take ILoginProvider interface as an argument:

```
class LoginHelper {

    private static ILoginProvider provider;

    // this method should be called somewhere in Application_Startup event in Global.asax
    public static void RegisterLoginProvider(ILoginProvider inst) {
        provider = inst; 
    }
}
```

and then write necessary methods:

```
public static bool IsLogged() {
    return provider.IsLogged();
}
```

and then call RegisterLoginProvider() method in Global.asax in Application_Startup event:

```
MyCustomProvider prov = new MyCustomProvider(); // this class implements ILoginProvider interface
LoginHelper.RegisterSecurityProvider(prov);
```

Is it a correct way to implement such logic to change some "providers" with others?

Comment: normally you would use the Provider based configuration model to define your providers in web.config plus selecting which one is the default. This is the way SiteMapProviders, MemberShipProviders, RoleProviders etc is implemented and its good practice to follow defactor standards http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.provider.providerbase.aspx

Comment: It is good practice to follow standards but not necessary, and besides, which implentation to go for is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is often done is via a service locator (Unity, StructureMap etc) or a custom factory where you ask for an instance of ILoginProvider and the correct one is returned.

The responsibility of selecting which kind of ILoginProvider to create is not up to the calling class.

```
//get a login provider from via a service locator
ILoginProvider provider = DependencyLookup.Resolve<ILoginProvider>();
```

With the service locators, you would register against ILoginProvider which implementation to use, either in XML configuration or in code.  Here is an example for Unity.

```
public static class ContainerConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        ServiceLocator.Current.RegisterType<ILoginProvider, XmlLoginProvider>();
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to find out which kind of ILoginProvider should i use? Maybe i should save a class name in web.config and then pass it to my LoginHelper class in such way: LoginHelper.RegisterLoginProvider(Activator.CreateInstance("My_Class_Name_From_web.config));? IoC and dependency lookup are difficult for my understanding...

Comment: All the hard work is done for you if you use one of the service locators.

Comment: OK, it becomes clearer. But what is ServiceLocator? Is it a class from Unity or MS Enterprise Library or simply an example? Thanks

Comment: I was referring to the use of Unity, or Structure Map, Castle Windsor etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have tried to abstract out the login functionalities which is very nice. Further you have to make this helper to page binding through DependencyInjecttion i.e you have to add a constrcutro to the class with LoginInterface as the argument. Then you can use utilities like StructureMap to get the instances at runtime.

By means of having the interfaces we can provide adaptability for future cases where you can move to DB or webservice.